# Clean-css NPM Command not found

Tags: node.js, npm, clean-css

I am trying to use clean-css to minify my CSS files using a simple terminal command on Mac. I have tried everything from installing an older version of clean-css like this:

```
npm install clean-css@3.4.25 --save
```

to installing the command line version like this:

```
npm install clean-css-cli --save
```

The installation seems to go fine, but then whenever I try to run

```
cleancss -o styles.min.css styles.css
```

I get an error saying, "command not found." Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If `clean-css` is also not in the package.json file of your project's directory, perhaps try to install it globally:

```
 npm install -g clean-css-cli
```

After installing, this should provide you the version that was installed (try in a new shell):

```
cleancss -v
```

I do not have a Mac, but I believe you will also be able to run through `npm` like so:

```
npm cleancss -v
```

In my case, the former presents `4.1.9` (CLI) and the latter `3.10.10` (API). More information of the [version 4 division in clean-css Github](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css#important-40-breaking-changes).